# thermoelectric generator

Tags: peltier, energy-harvesting

My question is can a thermoelectric generator(input:heat difference to output:electricity) module also work as a peltier module(Input: current to output:cooling effect)?

If I buy a thermoelectric generator, can I use it for cooling if I pump current into it?

Comment: What do the application examples in the datasheets show you? You need to show some research.

Comment: I don't think so. Use TEC (thermo electric cooler) instead.

Answer (score 2):

> My question is can a thermoelectric generator(input:heat difference to output:electricity) module also work as a peltier module(Input: current to output:cooling effect)?

Usually yes - BUT it is a very good idea to consult the manufacturer's data and see what they say. A TEG is usually a better specified TEC - it is usually able to run at higher hot-side temperatures and may have more "cells" to allow a greater voltage for a given temperature differential.

TEGS are usually more expensive than TECS of similar ratings - you need to have a good reason to use a TEG as a TEC.

You can use low cost Peltier coolers (TECs) as TEGs - with lower output and often lower efficiency than the apparently similar spec TEG.

TEG "Carnot efficiency is (Thot-Tcold)/Thot in absolute degrees eg degrees Kelvin where 0 C ~+ 273 K. Actual efficiency will be a smallish fraction of Carnot efficincy but increases with increasing temperature differential.
Real world TEGs typically give 5%+ efficiency with Thot = 200C and Tcold at around 30 C.

TEG = Thermoelectric Generator = Seebeck effect
TEC = Thermoelectric Cooler = Peltier effect

---

[Wikipedia Thermoelectric effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermoelectric_effect)

[Seebeck effect - images linked to web pages](https://www.google.co.nz/search?q=seebeck++effect&biw=1920&bih=1075&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjDq_eLvu3KAhUGX5QKHWWYDvsQsAQISg)